# Criterions for beta phase

Tags: discussion, meta

I roughly read all questions here, but one information is still missing for me. What are the criterions for GL&U to leave the beta phase? Is it a special amount of questions or users? Is there a general plan; e.g. until the end of this year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Area 51 proposal page (linked to from the top page): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage

> This site is in Public Beta
>   Anyone can participate!
>
> The site's progress will be evaluated in **74 days**.

Every new stack site goes through a 90 day beta phase, at which end it will be evaluated. You can see the criteria for what's considered a successful site on the aforelinked page.

If it is *really* unsuccessful, it may simply be killed. If it's so-so, it may stay in perpetual beta until interest picks up.

Comment: Most importantly, read the blog post: [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Comment: @RegDwight: Is the visits/day statistic calculated globally or only over the last two weeks or so?

Comment: @thei: [according to David](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/whats-the-difference-between-stackexchange-com-sites-traffic-numbers-and-area-51/66612#66612), it's "Average # of Visits each day for the past 14 days as recorded by Google Analytics".

Comment: The time is by far over. Is the the answer still correct? Where are we *now* with German Language? Does anyone know more?